# How do I get "createElement" not to repeat itself, but to replace the old information with the new?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, append, createelement

How do I make my "createElement" to replace the new information over the old and not as it is now that it adds more text all the time.
Or if that not possible, then to appentChild only to 1 row.

**The part if the code that needs a change:**

```
function bodyAppend(tagName, innerHTML) {
    var elm;

    elm = document.createElement(tagName);
    elm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
}
```

Remember that the createElement must work with the javascript above it too. It is not a stand alone function.
**The entire code source is is:**

```
function showFileSize() {
    var input, file;

    if (!window.FileReader) {
        bodyAppend("p", "The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
        return;
    }

    input = document.getElementById('fileToLoad');
    if (!input) {
        bodyAppend("p", "Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
    else if (!input.files) {
        bodyAppend("p", "This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
        bodyAppend("p", "Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
        file = input.files[0];
        bodyAppend("p", "File " + file.name + " is " + file.size + " bytes in size");
    }
}

function bodyAppend(tagName, innerHTML) {
    var elm;

    elm = document.createElement(tagName);
    elm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single  element. Since you want only one paragraph.

```
function showFileSize() {
    var input, file;

    if (!window.FileReader) {
        bodyAppend("id", "The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
        return;
    }

    input = document.getElementById('fileToLoad');
    if (!input) {
        bodyAppend("id", "Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
    else if (!input.files) {
        bodyAppend("id", "This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
        bodyAppend("id", "Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
        file = input.files[0];
        bodyAppend("id", "File " + file.name + " is " + file.size + " bytes in size");
    }
}

function bodyAppend(id, innerHTML) {
    var elm;

    elm = document.getElementbyId(id);
    elm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: It did not really work as it should. The above codes worked in such that not it just adds to the same raw instead of new raw.
And the second codes from under did not work at all. So I had to keep the old codes, because the new second codes did not work.
This is the part you gave me that did not work:

`function bodyAppend(id, innerHTML) {
    var elm;

    elm = document.getElementbyId(id);
    elm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}`

PS: I tried mixing with your code and could not figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Just an idea. Maybe it is easier to make it replace if it was a possibility to send that info to a text box line a `texarea` box or a `input type=text` box. In a `textaera` we would still need to make the code not repeat itself, but in a `input type=text` box it can never repeat itself if it makes new rows cause that can only show one row.
Just an idea. But on the other hand how do I make it to show in a `input type=text` box? I tried to use `getElementbyId` for it, but it did not work. Ormaybe I wrote something wrong. I do know.
Either way your solution did not work either.

Comment: Hahahaha Now it works. It was a silly small defect in your code. It should have bin `elm = document.getElementById("id");` and not `elm = document.getElementbyId(id);`... No wonder it did not work. The simple thing as forgetting two of the ` " ` was enough to not having it working.
Anyway now I it works in the element I made. A textarea element I made. THANK YOU though it was not perfect, it was nearly perfect. I tiny mistake made me try and not understand what was the problem. Logically It was fine, So I was scratching my head. Hahaha LOL
THANK YOU...

Comment: You misunderstood the the code. I asked you to create a paragraph element with id="someID" then pass the same id into bodyAppend function like bodyAppend("someID","some text");

Comment: My mistake, but now it works. I did create a paragraph element with some ID. The paragraph element was not the problem. After I put brackets on the `(id);` and made it into `("id");` it works. PS: The "id" name is not id I just presented as such. Actually the code looks like this `elm = document.getElementById("info");` and it works now. No need for the `bodyAppend("someID","some text");` to be changed, because `bodyAppend("p","some text");` works perfectly fine. The problem was in the second part of the code now changed too `elm = document.getElementById("info");` and it is working good now.

Comment: And of course I deleted `document.body.appendChild(elm);`

Comment: Sorry for my English that was not that good. I knew to put "paragraph elements", I just forgot what the words "paragraph elements" mean. It is like you know what to do, you just do not know what it is named or called and there for you name it something else when talking or explaining. That the solution was so simple in JS yet I could not find it, is the funny part. Sometimes it is the most simple solutions one over sees and over complicates things, not knowing what is wrong.